# can I encrypt string with .p12 file in iphone?

Tags: ios, security, cryptography

Can I encrypt data with .p12 file in iphone/ipad?

I tried with [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW13) but no luck.

My goal is to encrypt data with private key.

Comment: Data is encrypted with public key and decrypted with private key.

Comment: Since anyone could decrypt a message that was intended to be decrypted with a public key, there is no point in encrypting it with the private key. You'd generally sign it instead, which is encrypting a hash of the message with the private key. However, it doesn't seem like iOS prevents you from encrypting with the private key. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried with some code form apple docs but not able to find anything regarding encrypt with private key.